# Finding the subscript of an array in a function in c++

Tags: c++, c++14

I have this homework and i've completed this up to now. where i am stuck... 
Basically i need to get the largest amount of rainfall and display it (which i already do have completed it) but also the number of the month.

This is where i am having an intense headache...
could you guys help me out with some code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

double yearlyRainAverage(double[], const int);
double smallestRainfall(double [], const int);
double largestRainfall(double [], const int);
int searchHighestMonth(double[], int);

int main() {

    const int months = 12;
    double inchesOfRain[months];
    double sumOfAllMonths=0;


    int maxMonthPosition = searchHighestMonth(inchesOfRain, months);

    for (int count = 0; count < months; count++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter the rainfall (in inches) for month #"<< count + 1<<":  ";
        cin>>inchesOfRain[count];

        sumOfAllMonths += inchesOfRain[count];


        if(inchesOfRain[count] < 0){

            cout <<"Rainfall must be 0 or more.\n";
            cout<<"please re-enter: "<<endl;
            cout<<"Enter the rainfall (in inches) for month #"<< count + 1<<":  ";
            cin>>inchesOfRain[count];

        }

    }
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << endl;

    cout<<"the total rainfall for the year is "<<sumOfAllMonths<<" inches"<<endl;
    cout<<"the average is "<<yearlyRainAverage(inchesOfRain, 12)<<" inches"<<endl;

//    cout<<"The smallest amount of rainfall was: "<<smallestRainfall(inchesOfRain, 12)<<" inches ";
//    cout<<"in month "<<(monthPosition+1)<<endl;

    cout<<"The largest amount of rainfall was: "<<largestRainfall(inchesOfRain, 12)<<" inches ";
    cout<<"in month "<<maxMonthPosition+1<<endl;

    return 0;
}

double yearlyRainAverage(double inchesofrain[], const int months){
    double sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<months; i++){
        sum+=inchesofrain[i];
    }
    return sum/months;
}

double smallestRainfall(double inchesofrain[], const int months){
    double smallest;
    int i;

    smallest=inchesofrain[0];
    for(i=0; i < months; i++){
        if(inchesofrain[i] < smallest){
            smallest = inchesofrain[i];
        }
    }
    return smallest;

}


double largestRainfall(double inchesofrain[], const int months){
    double largest;
    int i;

    largest=inchesofrain[0];
    for(i=0; i < months; i++){
        if(inchesofrain[i] > largest){
            largest = inchesofrain[i];
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

Here is where i think is the issue. i think my logic is wrong. But, i am not sure.

```
int searchHighestMonth(double inchesofrain[], int value){

    int max = 0;
    for ( int i=1; i < value; ++i) {
        if ( inchesofrain[max] < inchesofrain[i] ) {
            max = i;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Yes, your logic is wrong. You "search for highest month" before any values are entered. Undefined behavior. Your computer is a very logical contraption. It does things in order. Step by step. From beginning to the end. One step at a time. Pop quiz: what is the very first thing in your `main()` you tell your computer to do? Small hint: it's not to enter the amount of rainfall and populate the array.

Comment: jesus crist... im so dumb. The answer was so simple....Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are searching for your largest rainfall before you have taken the input of your rainfall from the user.

Move this line:

```
    int maxMonthPosition = searchHighestMonth(inchesOfRain, months);
```

After the input for loop.

I went ahead and tested all of your code again, redirecting stdin (cin) from an input string, which I find very helpful for testing so I don't have to keep inputting. here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double yearlyRainAverage(double[], const int);
double smallestRainfall(double [], const int);
double largestRainfall(double [], const int);

int searchHighestMonth(double inchesofrain[], int value) {

    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < value; ++i) {
        if (inchesofrain[max] < inchesofrain[i]) {
            max = i;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

int main() {
//#define testing  // comment this line out to use std::cin for input
#ifdef testing
    // code to get stdin input from a local buffer
    std::string input_string{"4 5 6 7 8 9 10 3 2 3 4 5"};
    std::streambuf *orig = std::cin.rdbuf();
    std::istringstream input(input_string);
    std::cin.rdbuf(input.rdbuf());

#endif

    const int months = 12;
    double inchesOfRain[months];
    double sumOfAllMonths = 0;

    for (int count = 0; count < months; count++) {
        cout << "Enter the rainfall (in inches) for month #" << count + 1 << ":  " << std::endl;
        cin >> inchesOfRain[count];

        sumOfAllMonths += inchesOfRain[count];

        while (inchesOfRain[count] < 0) {
            cout << "Rainfall must be 0 or more.\n";
            cout << "please re-enter: " << endl;
            cout << "Enter the rainfall (in inches) for month #" << count + 1 << ":  " << std::endl;
            cin >> inchesOfRain[count];
        }
    }

    int maxMonthPosition = searchHighestMonth(inchesOfRain, months);

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << endl;

    cout << "the total rainfall for the year is " << sumOfAllMonths << " inches" << endl;
    cout << "the average is " << yearlyRainAverage(inchesOfRain, months) << " inches" << endl;

//    cout<<"The smallest amount of rainfall was: "<<smallestRainfall(inchesOfRain, 12)<<" inches ";
//    cout<<"in month "<<(monthPosition+1)<<endl;

    cout << "The largest amount of rainfall was: " << largestRainfall(inchesOfRain, 12) << " inches ";
    cout << "in month " << maxMonthPosition + 1 << endl;

#ifdef testing
    std::cin.rdbuf(orig);
#endif

    return 0;
}

double yearlyRainAverage(double inchesofrain[], const int months) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < months; i++) {
        sum += inchesofrain[i];
    }
    return sum / months;
}

double smallestRainfall(double inchesofrain[], const int months) {
    double smallest;
    int i;

    smallest = inchesofrain[0];
    for (i = 0; i < months; i++) {
        if (inchesofrain[i] < smallest) {
            smallest = inchesofrain[i];
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}

double largestRainfall(double inchesofrain[], const int months) {
    double largest;
    int i;

    largest = inchesofrain[0];
    for (i = 0; i < months; i++) {
        if (inchesofrain[i] > largest) {
            largest = inchesofrain[i];
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your searchHighestMonth() function is almost good. But its loop must start at 0 not 1, like in the rest of your code. Loop is from 0 to 11 if it is a full year with 12 months. Besides, it is more readable if you store the current maximum rain value in some variable.

```
int searchHighestMonth(double inchesofrain[], int monthcount){

    double maxrain = -1.0;
    int max = -1;

    for ( int i=0; i < monthcount; ++i) {
        if ( maxrain < inchesofrain[i] ) {
            maxrain = inchesofrain[i];
            max = i;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

**Side remark**: In actual production code, you would probably want to use std::vector objects, which maintain their own size, rather than plain old C-style arrays.

**Side remark**: if you want to give your user a second chance to enter a proper non-negative rainfall value, you must do it **before** including that value into the sum.

Comment: The problem is that the searchHighestMonth function is called prior to the input loop.  This change will not fix it.